# Example of a Differential equation whose solution is not defined for all time $t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a differential equation with its domain $R$  and an initial
condition for this equation such the solution is not defined for all time $t$.

Comment: What is the domain of a differential equation?

Comment: Try choosing a function which is not defined for all values of $t$, and then find a differential equation that it satisfies.

Comment: "Canu you think of such an example?" Yes I can. Next question?

Comment: Try something like $\frac{dy}{dt}=1+y^2$.

Comment: If anyone cares to explain to me what the domain of a differential equation is, I appreciate it.

Comment: @GitGud It's somewhat imprecisely stated: should be $y'=F(t,y)$ where $F$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2$. In practice, it's the $t$ dependency that is more likely to cause $F$ to be undefined. So, the emphasis is put on all $t\in\mathbb R$ being acceptable. For example $y'=y/(1-t)$ would not work for this problem because the equation itself is not defined when $t=1$.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly simplest example:
$$
y'=y^2,\quad y(0)=y_0>0.
$$

Comment: here solution is defined for all points of R except $y_0$??i.e defined for t>$y_0$ and t<$y_0$.I have to find a solution NOT defined for all t.

Comment: Have you made the effort to compute the solution?